# External CSS not being applied, but same code works when pasted as Internal

Tags: html, css, external

I'm a newbie learning the ways of html/css via online tutorials. Only now I've run into a little problem that I can't quite figure out, and I've tried suggestions to similar issues from this very site and more.

As the title says, my external css file just does not seem to work at all, though said code works fine if I apply it internally. I keep rereading the code trying to spot mistakes, but even css lint and codepen just seem to say I have overqualified  elements, and not much else. I've tried just using the class names e.g. .Attack instead of td.Attack, but that didn't help.

The html is basically a table with some images, and I am only trying to apply a single stylesheet. Here is tcgdatabase.css

```
body {
    background-color:transparent;
    }

p {
    color:#2E2435;
    text-align:justify;
    }

td {
    text-align:left;
    }
td.Name {
    text-align:left;
    width:250px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
td.Type {
    width:50px;
    }
td.Stage {
    text-align:left;
    width:120px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
td.HP,td.AP {
    width:50px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:30px;
    }
span.Points {
    font-size:15px;
    }
td.Attack,td.BaseDamage {
    height:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    }
td.Effect,td.Flavour {
    text-align:justify;
    }
td.WRR,td.WRRType {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
th {
    text-align:center;
    }
```

here is the html page, I even left the css in there enclosed with the  to show how I added it internally:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-GB">
        <head>
            <title>oddities</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/TCG/JBSet1/tcgdatabase.css">
            <!--<style>
body {
    background-color:transparent;
    }

p {
    color:#2E2435;
    text-align:justify;
    }

td {
    text-align:left;
    }
td.Name {
    text-align:left;
    width:250px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
td.Type {
    width:50px;
    }
td.Stage {
    text-align:left;
    width:120px;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
td.HP,td.AP {
    width:50px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:30px;
    }
span.Points {
    font-size:15px;
    }
td.Attack,td.Base Damage {
    height:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:20px;
    }
td.Effect,td.Flavour {
    text-align:justify;
    }
td.WRR,td.WRRType {
    height:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
th {
    text-align:center;
    }
            </style>-->
        </head>
        <body>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="9" style="width:420px"><img src="CacturneR.png" style="width:350px"></td>
                    <td class="Type"><img src="Energy Types/Dark.png" style="width:40px"></td>
                    <td class="Stage">Legendary</td>
                    <td class="Name">Yveltal</td>
                    <td class="HP">110<span class="Points">HP</span></td>
                    <td class="AP">0<span class="Points">AP</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class"AttackCost" colspan="2">
                        <img src="Energy Types/Dark.png" style="width:30px">
                        <img src="Energy Types/Colourless.png" style="width:30px">
                    </td>
                    <td class="Attack" colspan="2">Take In</td>
                    <td class="BaseDamage"><td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Effect" colspan="5">
                        Attach up to 3 Pokémon from your hand to this Pokémon and heal 10 damage from this 
                        Pokémon times the number of Pokémon cards just attached in this way. Each Pokémon attached 
                        in this way provides 1 Energy of their type at a time (If they have more than 1 type, 
                        they provide Energy of each of their types, but only 1 at a time).
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class"AttackCost" colspan="2">
                        <img src="Energy Types/Dark.png" style="width:30px">
                        <img src="Energy Types/Dark.png" style="width:30px">
                        <img src="Energy Types/Colourless.png" style="width:30px">
                        <img src="Energy Types/Colourless.png" style="width:30px">
                    </td>
                    <td class="Attack" colspan="2">Riot Ballista</td>
                    <td class="BaseDamage"><td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Effect" colspan="5">
                        Discard 1 card attached to this Pokémon. If that card is a Pokémon, this 
                        attack does damage equal to the discarded Pokémon's HP. If it is not a 
                        Pokémon, this attack does 50 damage and this Pokémon does 50 damage to 
                        itself.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="WRRType"><img src="Energy Types/Fairy.png" style="width:25px"></td>
                    <td class="WRR">weakness: x2</td>   
                    <td class="Flavour" colspan="3" rowspan="3">
                        "This terrible beast has long since turned a blind eye to the havoc it 
                        wreaks in its wake" - Anon.
                    </td>
                <tr>
                    <td class="WRRType"><img src="Energy Types/Fighting.png" style="width:25px"></td>                   
                    <td class="WRR">resistance: -20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                    
                    <td class="WRRType"><img src="Energy Types/colourless.png" style="width:25px"></td>                 
                    <td class="WRR">retreat cost: x2</td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Illus" colspan="3">Illus. NavaskaIII</td>
                    <td class="SetNumber">??/??</td>
                    <td class="Rarity">UR</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I feel like I am missing something completely obvious, I really would appreciate the help!

Comment: Do you mean if the href is correct? If so, I have checked. I pasted the same on my web browser (chrome) and the .css shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your link element change
    ref="stylesheet" to rel="stylesheet"

notice the 'f' should be 'l'

Comment: Oh wow, that was it! Thank you so much! As embarassed as I am for not spotting that, how did css lint not see that!?

Comment: oh wait because I never put the htm in css lint.  Codepen did not see it though!

Answer (score 0):

Check your path to the CSS file. I would recommend using a relative path to the file.

Change `href="file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/TCG/JBSet1/tcgdatabase.css"` to something like `href="/path/to/JBSet1/tcgdatabase.css"`.

If the CSS file is in the same folder as the HTML file, you can just use `href="tcgdatabase.css"`.

Edit:

As stated above, also change `ref="stylesheet"` to `rel="stylesheet"`.

Comment: It's in the same folder, and originally it was just "tcgdatabase.css". It didn't work. Just tried it again, same result. Even your last suggestion too :(

Comment: Make the change and do a force refresh using `Ctrl + F5` in case it is cached.

Comment: the ref was the problem, thank you so much! Such a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

Follow this syntax:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

Path of css file has to be relative or absolute path..